# Spyder (Python 3.8) web scraping question

Tags: python, web-scraping

Using the code below, I am trying to pull baseball lineups into a data frame. Starting at line 24, I am receiving the error "ValueError: not enough value to unpack (expected 2, got 1).  Is anyone able to assist in resolving this issue? Thanks!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2022-08-05"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

def get_name(tag):
    if tag.select_one(".desktop-name"):
        return tag.select_one(".desktop-name").get_text()
    elif tag.select_one(".mobile-name"):
        return tag.select_one(".mobile-name").get_text()
    else:
       return tag.get_text()

data = []
for card in soup.select(".lineup-card"):
    header = [
        c.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        for c in card.select(".lineup-card-header .c")
    ]
    h_p1, h_p2 = [
        get_name(p) for p in card.select(".lineup-card-header .player")
    ]
    data.append([*header, h_p1, h_p2])

    for p1, p2 in zip(
        card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(1) .player"),
        card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(2) .player"),
    ):
        p1 = get_name(p1).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
        p2 = get_name(p2).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]

        data.append([*header, p1, p2])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["Team1", "Date", "Team2", "Player1", "Player2"]
)
df.to_csv("MLB Games.csv", index=False)
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

I receive the following error code when running the code above:

```
\Users\15156\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 141, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'tabulate'.  Use pip or conda to install tabulate.
```

When I type %pip install tabulate into the console I receive this error message:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
C:\Users\15156\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\python.exe: No module named pip
```

However, if I restart the kernel I still receive the same error message.  I have looked around and tried installing the package using the code below:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\15156> conda activate base
(base) PS C:\Users\15156> conda create -n myenv spyder-kernels nltk
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.12.0
  latest version: 4.13.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\15156\miniconda3\envs\myenv

  added / updated specs:
    - nltk
    - spyder-kernels
```

The packages were downloaded and installed, and I have looked into where it says the environment location is, however when I run %pip install kernel again it still says that the module cannot be found, spitting out the same error as above.  Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: The `return` statements on their own lines in `get_name` are very suspicious, but I don't think they're actually causing your error directly, that's got to be `card.select(...)` only finding one value.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code. First, you don't `import requests`. Next, the first two `return` statements in `get_name()` don't have anything following them - you need to bring the next line up to that line. Finally, since `get_name()` is returning objects where you called the `get_text()` method on them, it is actually returning strings, so you don't need to access the `.text` attribute on them when you're assigning to `p1` and `p2`. Here is the corrected code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2022-08-05"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

def get_name(tag):
    if tag.select_one(".desktop-name"):
        return tag.select_one(".desktop-name").get_text()
    elif tag.select_one(".mobile-name"):
        return tag.select_one(".mobile-name").get_text()
    else:
       return tag.get_text()

data = []
for card in soup.select(".lineup-card"):
    header = [
        c.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        for c in card.select(".lineup-card-header .c")
    ]
    h_p1, h_p2 = [
        get_name(p) for p in card.select(".lineup-card-header .player")
    ]
    data.append([*header, h_p1, h_p2])

    for p1, p2 in zip(
        card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(1) .player"),
        card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(2) .player"),
    ):
        p1 = get_name(p1).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
        p2 = get_name(p2).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]

        data.append([*header, p1, p2])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["Team1", "Date", "Team2", "Player1", "Player2"]
)
df.to_csv("73264662.csv", index=False)
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

This prints:

```
| Team1   | Date             | Team2   | Player1               | Player2                  |
|:--------|:-----------------|:--------|:----------------------|:-------------------------|
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Edward Cabrera (R)    | Justin Steele (L)        |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Miguel Rojas (R) SS   | Rafael Ortega (L) CF     |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Joey Wendle (L) 2B    | Contreras                |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Garrett Cooper (R) 1B | Patrick Wisdom (R) 1B    |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Jesus Aguilar (R) DH  | Ian Happ (S) LF          |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | De La Cruz            | Nelson Velazquez (R) RF  |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | JJ Bleday (L) CF      | Yan Gomes (R) C          |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Peyton Burdick (R) LF | Zach McKinstry (L) 3B    |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Stallings             | Christopher Morel (R) SS |
| Marlins | August, 5 2:20pm | Cubs    | Leblanc               | Nick Madrigal (R) 2B     |
```

and produces a CSV with all of today's games.

Comment: Hi matt, Thank you for your help!  I am still getting the error in line 22, "ValueError: Not enough value to unpack (expected 2, got 1)" using the updated code you provided.  Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @Ben Please edit your question and post the [*full text* of the traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Do not put it in a comment.

Comment: just did it, thanks for helping a new user like me

Comment: Try running the code by putting it in a new `.py` file and running it from the command line. Alternatively, completely restart your IPython/Jupyter session.

Comment: Just did both of them and they did not resolve the issue

Comment: Hmm. I just found something interesting - I've been running the code with Python 3.10, since that's what my default development environment is using, but I just ran it using 3.8 and got the same error you did. However, in Line 6, if I change `"html.parser"` to `"lxml"`, it works. Curious...

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: I updated spyder and it ran.  I have two questions though - 1) do you know why some players names only populate their last names and others have their full lames and positions? 2) I received an error message. I have updated the post that shows the new message, do you know what this means?

Comment: The post hasn't updated. Please make sure you save your edits.

Comment: It is showing that it it updated on my end.  Do you see it now?

Comment: Got it. I got that error initially as well. You just need to run `pip install tabulate` and it should work fine.

Comment: If I type in `pip install tabulate` It tells me that the syntax is invalid.... any advice?

Comment: You need to run it from the command line, or within IPython/Jupyter by prefixing it with a `!` like so: `!pip install tabulate`.

Comment: I have edited my post.  Would you mind taking a look and seeing if you have run into this issue before?  Thanks!